# Can set only HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS header in angular2 app

Tags: angular, request

I have some problem with set headers on frontend. 
Base data: frontend(angular2), backend(sinatra). I want to send request to backend with auth key. I know about Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers on backend, because i use cross-domain request. I use `sinatra-cross_origin` gem for it.
Code for sending:

```
   const headers = new Headers({'Authorization': 'key'});
   return this.http.get("http://0.0.0.0:9292/api/products", {headers: headers})
  .map(this.extractData)
  .catch(this.handleError);
```

But when i see on request headers on backend - i see

```
'HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS' => authorization
```

How i can set custom header? Where is error?

I try to send JWT key, and server side i create like in tutorial
https://devblast.com/b/cors-with-angular-js-and-sinatra
If i send request from Postman - all is working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to enable the 'HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS' in WEB API, see the below code

```
 app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
```

Comment: Th'x tor answer, but i think, problem on frontend. If i send request with Postman - all right. I added more data about problem on question.